# Sort by Most Mentioned Word and Least Mentioned word in MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working on Holy Quran. I have to sort the Chapters by Most Mentioned Words and Least Mentioned words.

I am using MySql as database and Quran Chapters are stored in table as paragraph.

I think I should count all the words in Quran using PHP. On the basis of that I can sort the Chapters.

Below is the code to extract the keywords from paragraph and stored in Keywords.

I think the below solution is lengthy one. I am not sure that using the above solution I can get the exact results. If there is any other solution please let me know.

```
public function insertKeywords(){
  set_time_limit(0);
  set_time_limit(3000000);
  $allData = Quran::select('*')->paginate(1000);
  foreach($allData as $data) {
    $newData = explode(" ",$data->AyahText);
    foreach($newData as $keyWord) {
      # Check data already exist
      $findWord = Keyword::select('*')->where('Keyword','=', $keyWord)->first();
        if($findWord) {
          $count = $findWord->KeywordCount+1;
          #Update
          Keyword::where('ID','=',$findWord->ID)->update(['KeywordCount' => $count]);
        } else {
          $count = 1;
          Keyword::insert([
            'Keyword'=> $keyWord,
            'VerseID' => $data->VerseID,
            'SuraID' => $data->SuraID,
            'AyahTextID' => $data->AyahTextID,
            'LanguageID' => $data->LanguageId,
            'KeywordCount' => $count
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Read the Qur'an in batches, and use an in memory hash map to keep track of the counts.